# HttpClient in Xamarin.Forms throwing "An error occurred while sending the request."

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I use Xamarin.Forms to develop a multiplateform app on Windows(UWP) and Android. Also I use a WebService from an ERP running on the LAN of the Enterprise I work. This WebService is available in a normal request in C# with WebRequest and it works fine. But Xamarin prefers, with several plateforms, to use HttpClient with asynchronous methods. The WebRequest indeed doesn't work with android, and it locks the UI in UWP.

So I created a RestService like its in MSDN and no way to make the request responding. Just if I put the request with WebRequest just before the request with HttpClient, it works and I receive the XML like I want.

If I put only the HttpClient Request it throws a simple error → HttpRequestException with just ("An error occurred while sending the request.").
The InnerException is → "The text associated with this error code cannot be found. The certification authority is not valid or correct."

The goal is multiplatform so HttpClient is required I think, I've already tried to put certificates validations and searched on many forums without finding the answer!!

Hope Somebody can help me!

### Request working with WebRequest

```
public string Request(string uri)
{
     string responseFromServer = "";
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pswd);
     request.Method = "GET";

     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

     if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription == "OK")
     {
          Stream dataStream;
          using (dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
          {
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
               responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
          }
     }
     response.Close();

     return responseFromServer;
}
```

### My request with HttpClient

```
//Constructor 
public RestService()
{
     //Authentification for the request header
     user = "**";
     pswd = "*****";
     society= "*****";
     user = "%CP1252%" + Base64Encode(user + "@@" + society+ "@@00000");
     pswd = Base64Encode(pswd );
     var authData = string.Format("{0}{1}", user, mdp);

     client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authData);

     //Security protocol
     ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
}

//Request method
public async Task<string> GetDatas(string url)
{
     Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
     string content = "";

     try
     {
          HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     }
     catch (HttpRequestException e)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
     return content;
}
```

### Where I do my request in the MockDataStore to fill a list of objects

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Operation>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
{
     GetOperations(); // call WebRequest Method

     await GetOperationsAsync(); // call HttpClient Method

     return await Task.FromResult(Operations);
}
```

### Attempt to custom default headers of httpclient instance with GetStringAsync

```
client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authData);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Mozilla", "5.0"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("AppleWebKit", "537.36"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Chrome", "91.0.4472.114"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Safari", "537.36"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "srverp:****";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("fr-FR"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("keep-alive");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Pragma.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("no-cache"));
```

### Attempt to custom headers of the request using sendAsync

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
     RequestUri = uri,
     Method = HttpMethod.Get,
     Headers = {
          { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Basic " + authData},
          { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/xml" }
     },
};

var task = client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith((taskwithmsg) =>
{
     var response = taskwithmsg.Result;
     var tmp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     content = tmp.Result;
});
task.Wait();
```

Comment: I try, as you mentionned, to custom headers of the httpclient instance using the GetStringAsync Method and same error! Also try to custom the header for each request via HttpRequestMessage as you can see in my code above. With the second method I use SendAsync and same exception!

Comment: The useragent may be wrong which specifies the browser that is being a client.  It may be required with some server even though you are using httpclient.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent?force_isolation=true

Comment: Sound like a kernel issue on Android.  Not sure how to find.  See : https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+log

Comment: Added in my DefaultRequestHeaders in my fisrt method almost all what I found in my request header and user-agent but the error still remaining! I keep searching for a solution.

Comment: I've test many things, so it seems it's due to xamarin on my request to the ERP on the LAN of the enterprise, the request works with HttpClient in a normal C# project and the HttpClient Request works nicely in xamarin to get ressources from others websites, so I still blocked

Comment: You may have a OAuth2 issue.  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/oauth-login-authenticating-with-identity-provider-in-xamarin-forms/?force_isolation=true

Comment: The Authorization Header is correct, I've got the same "Basic" authentification in C# project working with WebRequest and HttpClient to get datas from the ERP! I don't need an OAuth2 authentification. Same with Postman I've got, the basic Auth works. I'll try just in case, thanks for your help!

Comment: Best thing is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture first request in working and non working condition.  For this test I would recommend using http instead of https.  All we want to find out is if the headers in the working request matches the non working.  We do not card if the connection completes.  So using HTTP will not encrypt making it easier to see differences.

Comment: I see, the problem is that the WebService provided is in https and I cannot change it. I can't sniff the network so ! But in Debug mode I can see what's inside my httpClient instance and resquest and I see nothing anormal I don't really know maybe

Comment: The service should be transparent to the type of client.  The default headers in httprequest are different than other methods.  It is also possible the version of http (1.0 vs 1.1) may be different.  We need to compare the good and the bad.  Maybe create a test server and capture the entire request for good and bad.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a bad cookie.  So if you go to your browser and delete cookies then try again.  The same cookies are in the browser that c# uses.

Comment: You were right on the default header just it's seems it's better to pass by a handler. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the header of the httpClient in a Handler instance like this :

```
public HttpClient HttpclientAccount
{
     get
     {
          client = client ?? new HttpClient
          (
               new HttpClientHandler()
               {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                    {
                         //bypass
                         return true;
                    },
               }
               , false
          );

          // authentification headers
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", 
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{user}:{mdp}")));
          return client;
     }
}
```

Using this method, the authentification works and the response is good!